# Is Unreal Engine 4 C++ managed or unmanaged?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Unreal Engine 4 controls some runtime aspects of the application, such as having its own Garbage Collector and a unique metadata ("reflection") system.

The question is: is it correct to say UE4 makes the C++ code "managed" in the context of "managed" and "unmanaged" languages (as in C# is a managed language and C++ is an unmanaged language)?

Comment: Why does it matter? The answer has no effect on how you program it. What is your programming question? Is there something that isn't working? Share your code.

Comment: @RaymondChen are you suggesting that understanding concepts does not matter? I don't have code to share as it is a conceptual question. Is there a more suitable stackexchange site to post this question?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164332/managed-languages-vs-compiled-language-difference

Comment: @bolov I think I found my answer in that other question, thanks!

Comment: @underthevoid Not sure what you mean by "UE4 C++". That's not a language, UE4 is more like a library or framework. To use it, you must write your own C++ code, which is native code that does not run in a sandbox, and is not confined to the UE4 facilities. I don't see how you could call that "*managed*", or even question whether it is "*managed*".

Comment: @dxiv "sandbox" was the missing piece of the puzzle. In order the language to be considered managed it needs the application to be confined in a runtime that controls the the environment whilst UE4 framework is just that: a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "managed" you mean "managed memory" meaning "garbage collected" then C++ allows you to opt-in to that if you so wish, but by default it does not offer such a thing.

C#, like Java and many others, forces garbage collection on you, there is no way around it.

In C++ you can use things like [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to wrap around any objects you want to be garbage collected.

Remember that in C++ there's many ways to allocate and initialize. In situations where performance must be optimized at the expense of complexity it's not uncommon to write a custom allocator that can cut a lot of corners so long as it's used a very specific way.

So in other words C++ is "managed" *if you want* and *how you want it to be managed*. Management in C++ is a process you're an active participant in.

Comment: By "manage" I was not only referring to managed memory. I was referring to term used in the context of "managed vs unmanaged languages" (like in Java vs C++). Which implies complete runtime management. Unreal Engine 4 does some runtime management. My question was whether it is correct to say the C++ code you create to run under the UE4 framework is managed or not in the same way Java is known to be a managed language.

Comment: Normally the term "managed" doesn't come up in that sense, at least not in the C++ world. In the C++ world, like I said, you can opt-in, and UE4 provides some facilities for that. In Java/C# you have no choice, it's already garbage collected. You can do a lot of things in UE4 that don't involve the Engine at all, so it's not like Unity where you're going to have to deal with the garbage collector at every turn.

Comment: I think the thing you're missing here is that in C++ we talk mostly about "ownership" in terms of [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), not in terms of "management". Every allocation must have an owner, either implied or explicit, so that it can be cleaned up properly. UE4 provides tools to help facilitate this, but so does C++ itself, as does just coding it correctly and cleaning up your mess with destructors and such.

Comment: So even considering the runtime management UE4 does it is still an unmanaged language/context, right? I wonder what a framework like UE4 needs to be in order for it to be called a managed language/context (again: in the context of managed vs unmanaged languages); do you happen to have any clue on that?

Comment: I'm specifically saying that the very term "managed" doesn't apply to C++, it's not used, it's not relevant, it's just too general a term. C++ has very specific ways of "managing" and they're all quite different in how they play out, so talking about them in aggregate is usually meaningless. C# and Java don't have this, so they can lump it all together and call it "managed". So yeah, it's "unmanaged" in that you don't get anything by default, but also "managed" if you opt-in.

Comment: To look at other examples, Swift is "garbage collected", so by your definition, "managed". Rust allows you to pick and choose, you can opt-in like C++, or you can skip that for performance or simplicity. It's "unmanaged" but it provides "managed" facilities really easily should you want them.

Comment: "RIAA" do you mean [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)?

Comment: I think if you just avoided the loaded term "managed" and instead focused on garbage collection you'd have a much better understanding of how this works. In C++ "lifecycle management" is often quite complex and nuanced, it has many implications and obligations as per RAII. In a garbage collected language you can just write YOLO code where you literally don't need to care. In C++ you must pay attention to how you're managing your memory.

Comment: @tadman no worries, I was just checking to see if there is a technique I haven't heard of :)

Comment: My definition for "managed" is not only having a garbage collector. Languages like C# and Java are called "managed" because they have a complete runtime manager. This manager controls much more things besides garbage collection.

Comment: I think "managed" is a C#-ism that doesn't really apply to other langauges.

Comment: Java is considered a managed language in that extent.

Comment: If you're ultimately asking if C++ is like C# or Java then the answer is no. Java was heavily inspired by C++, but is a different language, and C# was perhaps "inspired" by Java, at least that's what Microsoft's legal department will only admit under duress.

Comment: I'm asking if UE4's framework and runtime manager could be considered something similar to the C#'s CLR.Net or the Java's JVM (which are what makes those languages "managed").

Comment: It does both a lot more and a lot less, so the answer is more complicated than a simple yes or no. A better example would be to look at Blueprint where it's pretty easy to say "yes" since you're not responsible for managing memory at all. When writing C++ code in UE you need to pay careful attention to what you're doing and how you're managing it or else you will just make a mess of things in ways that aren't possible in C# or Java.

Comment: A garbage collector is a very smart piece of software. Saying that std::shared_ptr is like garbage collector is ... well garbage. There is also a way to avoid garbage collection in C# and Java. All you need to do is to keep all allocated objects referenced and reuse them. This will give you complexity of C++

Comment: @OptionalOption It's a reference-counted pointer, just like Swift, Rust and others have, so no, it's not the same as a full-featured garbage collector, there are limitations, but it's generally adequate if used correctly. Not all garbage collectors are created equal, some are pretty terrible, some are truly awful. Java and C# have good implementations, but they're not without drawbacks. Even JavaScript, which generally has a really good garbage collector, is not without some severe faults.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not a managed langue. There is C++/CLI in visual studio that's managed, but it's not really C++.  Things like garbage collection can be implemented in C++ code with some work and is useful for some applications (I've had to do that). Even reflection is possible with a lot more work but it's not natively supported. Reflection does not really mean calling the compiler in your code.  You can even do that in C.